# Why does file_put_contents have permission issues when run from the browser?

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions

This question has been asked a couple of times up here, but I haven't found a solution yet. I have a Fedora 19 LAMP server and I just want to run the simple command: `file_put_contents('test.txt', 'Hello there');` in order to confirm that my web server can use PHP to write data to files. I'm having trouble figuring out a proper permissions scheme. To start, just for development, Apache's document root is `/var/www/html`. This directory was originally owned by a user and group called `www-data`, but I changed the directory's group to the primary group of the owner of the httpd process, named `apache`. It is this owner that is active when PHP runs. I've confirmed this with the following:

[image]

As you see, the process owner is `apache`, the current direcory is `/var/www/html/php-console`. The directory is owned by `www-data` and members of the group `apache` have full access to it.

I have tried the following to get PHP to actually create a file in this location, but to no avail:

```
chmod 777 /var/www/html/php-console

chown apache /var/www/html/php-console
chgrp apache /var/www/html/php-console

cd /var/www/html; > test.txt; chmod 777 test.txt;
```

Nothing will work while this script is run from the browser. However, when I use `file_put_contents` with the PHP CLI, it works just like I would expect, provided that the user I'm entering commands as or its group has write permissions to this directory or test file.

[image]

So, from the command line, you see how `www-data` has read, write, and execute permissions to the folder I'm in. `posix_getpwuid` and `posix_geteuid` help you to find the owner of the Apache/PHP process, which in this case is the same as the user logged into the console. `file_put_contents` succesfully writes 8 bytes to the specified file. If I change the group or owner and group to something else, I get Permission denied, which absolutely makes sense.

If this works on the command line, then why not when I really want it to, i.e., while actually serving web pages???

Comment: Weird... so I thought I'd try doing `chmod 777 /var/www/html/php-console` one more time, and this time it let me write to the file. I then changed it back to `775` and I could still run `file_put_contents` with no permission error. I rebooted my computer and I can still run this code okay. I decided to change the file context of `/var/www` from `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` to `httpd_sys_content_t` and it still works. I then tried turning off `httpd_unified`, and I got the permission error again. I'm not totally sure if it was turned off in the first place. Anyway, thank you for your help, Ignacio

Comment: One more note: When I turn off `httpd_unified`, then the `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` file context is indeed necessary to write files with PHP. Very interesting...

Comment: I recently had to revisit this question. It's come to my attention that on both my Ubuntu and Fedora machine, the real key to enabling `file_put_contents` to write to a file or directory was making sure that the process owner of PHP (`apache` on F19 and `www-data` on the Ubuntu 13.10) also had write permissions to that file or directory. My Ubuntu machine doesn't have SELinux, but I did have to make sure that policy manager was configured right on Fedora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you forgot to read the `httpd_selinux(8)` man page and give the directory the appropriate file context to allow the web server to write files there.

Comment: I greatly appreciate you bringing this to my attention. I've been reading `httpd_selinux(8)` as well as other online discussions and I'm not clear on what file context I should set. As far as the sebooleans, `getsebool` on my system tells me that httpd_builtin_scripting, httpd_unified and httpd_enable_cgi are on. I then ran:
<!-- language: bash -->
    semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/var/www(/.*)?"
    restorecon -R -v /var/www

To simply give everything there httpd sys read/write access, but I still get permission denied...

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally copied the wrong text in my comment. I indeed set the file context of everything under `/var/www` to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`. The command `ls -dZ /var/www/html/php-console`, regarding the file context of the directory I'm most interested in presently, returns what I'd expect:

`drwxrwxr-x. www-data www-data unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 /var/www/html/php-console`

Yet still my code snippet in php-console gives me 'Permission denied'. The `ls -Zd` command passed through `exec` in my snippet confirms the same file context. Sigh... any other thoughts?

Comment: @williamcwilliams: Give `audit2why -a -l` a try. You may want to redirect the results into a file for easier processing.